# How to slice a tensor with 'None' dimension?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am just using TensorFlow to realise a CNN model called DVF: https://github.com/liuziwei7/voxel-flow.

The output of the model is 'deconv4' with the shape of [batch_size, 256, 256,3], then I need to extract optical flow using command:'flow = tf.slice(deconv4.outputs, [0,0,0,0], [batch_size, 256, 256, 2])'.

However, if the 'batch_size' is 'None', how do I slice the 'flow' tensor?

Thanks in advance.

The shape of 'deconv4' is [?,256,256,3] and I want to obtain the 'flow' with the shape of [?,256,256,2] from the 'deconv4'.

```
deconv4 = Conv2d(deconv3_bn_relu, 3, [5, 5], act=tf.tanh, padding='SAME', W_init=w_init, name='deconv4')

    #################### Calculate Voxel Flow based on the 'deconv4' ############################
    flow = tf.slice(deconv4.outputs, [0,0,0,0], [batch_size, 256, 256, 2])
```

The shape of 'flow' should be [?, 256,256,2]. But I am not sure how to obtain it.

Comment: For any dimension you want to be dynamic you can use `None`.

Comment: @ARAT Thanks for your help. I tried to use 'None' in 'tf.slice', but I noticed that I could not directly replace the 'batch_size' with 'None', otherwise, it returns an error. Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace your batch_size with `None` and that should do the trick.

Alternatively, this: `tf.shape(x)[0]` will give you a variable tensor with your batch size.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! The issue has been solved. I would have an another question: the shape of 'deconv4.outputs' is [16,256,256,3], when I use the 'tf.shape(deconv4.outputs)[0]', why the result is : 'Tensor("FRUC_DVF_g/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32, device=/device:GPU:0)', not '16' ?? Thanks!